# Dynamic menu based on permissions in Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I would like to make a dynamic menu based on the permissions of a user. I have a table where I store the permissions as well as the user id which is related to the user table. This way I would spend hiding or showing items depending on whether you have permission to see that link.

For example: Assuming that I have in the menu the option Permission 1 and Permission 2, I would like that if the user has the permission assigned to that option it is shown in the menu "Permission 1" and hide "Permission 2", and vice versa. If you had both permissions, both elements would be displayed. I don't know if there's any way I can do it once and use that feature on all controllers, and not go one by one on my created controllers.

I have managed to do this by making a query in the database in each method to validate if it has the permission. If not, it shows the message "You do not have permission" but this way if I am showing the elements and what I want is that they are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

1. First make a table for Menu List (menuId, menuName, menuUrl)
2. Create another table User permissions (permId, userId, menuId), where menuId refers to the Menu List table.
3. For a user keep adding rows in User permissions table for multiple menus.
4. Lastly, get the whole list by joining Menu List and User permissions and using a where condition `where userId = 123`.
5. You will get the array of dynamic Menus. In view file do a `foreach($menus as $menu){...}`

For backend checks , no need to add check in all controllers

1. Go to BaseController.php
2. `__construct() { parent::__construct(); Add a function here to check access control }`